# forceNew in engine.io-client

Tags: socket.io, engine.io

I would like to test my engine.io server with multiple connections.
I am trying to open sockets in loop, but output is only one socket.

In socket.io-client I added `forceNew: true` and fixed the issue but not working with engine.io-client.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var socket = require('engine.io-client')('ws://localhost');
    socket.on('open', function(){

        console.log('socket opened : '+socket.id);

        socket.on('message', function(data){
          console.log('data is '+data);
        });

        socket.on('close', function(){
          console.log('socket closed : '+socket.id);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What else have you tried? And be more speciffic about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: a simple code for generating multiple open sockets from server-B to server-A to test memory and cpu usage !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the socket.io-client, you have to set `multiplex: false`.

> It creates a new Manager for the given URL, and attempts
>   to reuse an existing Manager for subsequent calls, unless the
>   multiplex option is passed with false. Passing this option is the equivalent of passing 'force new connection': true.

More at: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/

However, there seems to be no such implementation for "engine.io-client" and I don't think there will be either.

> The recommended framework for building realtime applications is Socket.IO, since it provides fundamental features for real-world applications such as multiplexing, reconnection support, etc.

From: https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io